# How to create namespace in existing azure Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

There is no document to create namespace in existing kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

#### Create namespace

`kubectl create ns <name>`

- A a more detailed example:
  https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/01-Namespace
- Official docs:
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#creating-a-new-namespace

#### Check namespace(s)

`kubectl get ns`

---

[image]